# Adding paragraph of information in Android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to create a story app which contains number of activities with large paragraph of text.Do I have to add the text in my strings file or is the any other method. Does adding paragraphs of text in string.XML is a good practice, will it increase the size of the app...please tell me if there is any other bet method

Comment: better add you in String.xml

Comment: I think you should put file in a server and load content when openning app. Only save a little story in String.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add it to strings.xml but it is best practice. It will probably do very little to the size of your app. One MB of text is a million characters in utf-8. If text is to long for system to handle, break it up in chunks.

Comment: To further aid in the answer, the Strings file was meant to be a repository for `strings`. The encode will be small enough, so as adding in the class as a string, or adding in the XML will yeld almost the same size, but would load faster, and allow to make usage of other apps/functions (such as localizations, and help updating, since it would always be in the same "spot", in the IDE).... to put it simple, Yes, adding in Strings.xml is a good choice

Comment: @Bonatti Thanks will now proceed with my project